# Raw document on GitHub or GitLab indents too far?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

When making gists or snippets on GitHub or GitLab they wont indent properly.

Using json like:

```
{
    "server": {
        "host": "127.0.0.1",
        "port": 1232,
    },
}
```

Becomes this in raw:

```
{
        "server": {
                "host": "127.0.0.1",
                "port": 1232,
        },
}
```

Why does it do this? I need to do this on Gitlab.

Comment: Are you using tabs for indentation? The width of a tab is decided by whatever renders it.

Comment: I don't get the option to choose, your comment should be is GitHub using tabs for indentation.

Comment: Update: picking either on Gists doesn't fix this.

Comment: It is possible to clone a gist and edit it locally.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is caused by the fact that your upload files containing tabs.

Tabs have the property that the program viewing them decides their length. Your editor is probably configured for a size of 4, while most browsers are using 8 width.

If you use spaces instead, the file looks the same length everywhere, where you have the side effect that no-one can customize the presentation to their preferred standard.

On Github gist, you can change the default what happens when you press the tab key on the top right of the file:

[image]

As your file is JSON, it the indentation doesn't matter for the result anyway.